# How to execute if there's a certain block within a radius

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to figure out how to execute (for example **/say hi**) when there's Yellow Terracotta in a certain radius or field, however I can't figure out how to do it.
Anyone knows?

Comment: Should probably ask this on https://gaming.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

Using Minecraft 1.16,

"[Execute](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/execute)" command has several syntax options. You can use the form "execute if block     run "

Using the [proper block name](https://minecraft-ids.grahamedgecombe.com/), we can get:

```
execute if block 1015 63 989 minecraft:yellow_glazed_terracotta run say hi
```

This targets a specific position.

I am a little less clear on how to achieve specifically what you are asking, but here are my thoughts:

The syntax provides for another form "execute if blocks..." This form allows you to select a range by corners, but it must be compared against a third selection of the exact same size (only the corner can be specified). I think the regions must be exactly the same, and may not allow for random placement of the block anywhere within the region.

Another way might be using different execute if commands instead to select an entity, and test where the entity is standing.

If you put a button on a command block and set it to:

```
execute at @p if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:yellow_glazed_terracotta run say hi
```

When the player hits the button on the command block (obviously they must be within range of the button to press it) it shall check if the block -1 under the @p is "yellow_glazed_terracotta", and it will run say hi.

@p can be modified with [distance=..3] which means the player targeted by the command block must be within 3 blocks of the command block:

```
execute at @p[distance=..3] if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:yellow_glazed_terracotta run say hi
```

So, this is sort of creating that range that you were looking for.

Some [sources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHS2AUTYFM8) use "execute as @a at @s..." as a way to target any player when they step on a certain block anywhere at anytime. It may be possible to modify this into a distance as well, but it seems that the player will need to stand at a specific relative position to the terracotta.

If I find a better way to achieve this, I'll follow up.

The subreddit [r/MinecraftCommands](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands) has a decent community that messes with Minecraft commands and command blocks. They may have further insight.

If I find a better way to achieve this, I'll follow up.

Edit- The only other thing I can think at this point is to take the first command I suggested and repeat it for every single coordinate in an area. If a terracotta block is any of those spaces, it will run the say hi command.

If you place all of these command lines into a [function](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Function_(Java_Edition)) file you can call for the function when the command block is activated.